# django - best way to get a datetime object from separate date and time picker jquery tools on a template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Is the best way to make a datetime object from separate date and time inputs on a template to use  datetime.combine(date object, time object) in the view?  I've been spinning my wheels a bit on this one and help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This feature already exists in the Django admin. Have you looked at how that is implemented?

Comment: I have looked, but most of the comments here on stackoverflow suggest that trying to use the django admin widget is not a good idea because it requires unsupported stuff that may change without warning in the future.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you use the admin widget. I was suggesting that you read the source as a starting point for your own implementation.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to reinvent the wheel.  I found this and it seems to work well, including timezone aware :  http://bradmontgomery.net/blog/extending-djangos-multiwidget-splitselectdatetimewidget/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [forms.SplitDateTimeWidget()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget)